# Why is the comma in two text fields put at the same time without focusing?

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

How can I change conditions in code when comma is pressed? So that the comma does not appear simultaneously in two text boxes 1 and 2 when typing, but separately? The same thing happens with the limitation of characters in these text fields. How to split the processing of two text fields among themselves! Why is the comma placed without focusing text fields?
Foto:
[image]
Complete code:

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
Textfield X9;
Textfield X10;

void setup() {
  size(700,400);
  
  PFont font = createFont("arial",20);
  
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  X9 = cp5.addTextfield("1")
     .setPosition(20,100)
     .setSize(200,40);
     X9.setInputFilter(ControlP5.INTEGER)
     .setFont(font)
     .setAutoClear(false)
     .setColor(color(255,0,0))
     ;
                 
  X10 = cp5.addTextfield("2")
     .setPosition(20,170)
     .setSize(200,40);
     X10.setInputFilter(ControlP5.INTEGER)
     .setFont(createFont("arial",20))
     .setAutoClear(false)
     ;
     
  textFont(font);}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if (e.getKey() == ','){
  X9.setText(X9.getText() + ',');}
  {
//  if(X10.getText().length()>=4) { X10.setText(X10.getText().substring(0, 3));}
  {
if (e.getKey() == ','){
  X10.setText(X10.getText() + ',');}
  {
 // if(X9.getText().length()>=4) { X9.setText(X9.getText().substring(0, 3));}
  }}}
}
```

Comment: To help you ask better questions: Your code formatting is terrible and makes it pretty hard to read/understand it. You should try linting it before posting it to SO. Then your question is hard to parse for other people because you ask several things without giving enough context. You should try to focus on one question: What is your code doing, exactly and what do you want it to do? I think your problem comes from the fact that in `keyPressed` you have the same code `X9.setText(X9.getText() + ',');}` for `X9` and `X10` which create this duplicate behavior, but we need more details.

Comment: My code is adding commas to text fields on keystrokes. How can I avoid duplicates in both fields? When typing a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the comma placed without focusing text fields?

Because you are using the global `keyPressed()` event.
This condition: `if (e.getKey() == ',')` checks that the `,` key is pressed and it's redundant to check twice in your case. It's equivalent to this simpler/cleaner snippet:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if (key == ','){
    X9.setText(X9.getText() + ',');
    X10.setText(X10.getText() + ',');
  }
}
```

There isn't any check if a field is focused or not.

You probably meant something like this ?:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if (key == ',') {
    if (X9.isFocus()) {
      X9.setText(X9.getText() + ',');
    }
    if (X10.isFocus()) {
      X10.setText(X10.getText() + ',');
    }
  }
}
```

Overall it's unclear what the main goal is. Perhaps there's a simpler way to achieve it ?

Remeber that you can listen for individual controlP5 component events via `void controlEvent(ControlEvent event)`. See **Processing > Examples > Contributed Libraries > ControlP5 > controllers > ControlP5Textfield** for a nice demo.

Additionally I recommend formatting/keeping code tidy. It may be a quick throw-away sketch, but buiilding a good habbit will pay off as you'll spend way more time reading code than writing code. As your programs become larger and larger you'll want to make life easier for your future self :)

**Update** Based on your comments here is a minimal sketch that should allow you control a floating point number between 7.4 and 16.8 and an integer number between 1800-1900:

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

int serialInt = 1800;

float serialFloat = 7.4;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  noStroke();
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  cp5.addNumberbox("serialInt")           // notice the component name matches the variable name: controlP5 links the two for you
     .setBroadcast(false)                 // disable events while we update value specific properties 
     .setPosition(100,100)                // screen location
     .setSize(100,20)                     // screen dimensions
     .setMultiplier(10)                   // set the sensitifity of the numberbox: each step is 10
     .setDirection(Controller.HORIZONTAL) // change the control direction to left/right
     .setRange(1800, 9000)                // set minimum, maximum value
     .setBroadcast(true)                  // enable events (after setting range)
     ;
  

  cp5.addNumberbox("serialFloat")
     .setBroadcast(false)                 // disable events while we update value specific properties
     .setPosition(100,140)                // screen location
     .setSize(100,20)                     // screen dimensions
     .setMultiplier(0.01)                 // set the sensitifity of the numberbox: each step is 0.01
     .setDirection(Controller.HORIZONTAL) // change the control direction to left/right
     .setRange(7.4,16.8)                  // set minimum, maximum value
     .setBroadcast(true)                  // enable events (after setting range)
     ;
  
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
}
// gets called whenever a component updates value
void controlEvent(ControlEvent event){
  println(event.getController().getName(),"changed value to",event.getValue(),"serialInt = ",serialInt,"serialFloat = ",serialFloat);
}
```

Click and drag horizontally to change values.
Notice a few helpful things that ControlP5 provides:

- if you name your controller the same name as the controller the two are connected automatically: huge time saver. (If you can't use variable safe name you can look at **Examples > Contributed Examples > ControlP5 > use > ControlP5plugTo**)
- you can easily set the range and precision desired
- you can use `controlEvent()` optionally to tell when a value changed

Regarding data over serial:

- 7.4 to 16.8 range is easy if you only need .1 precision: simply multiply the value by 10 bringing it to 74 to 168 which fits within a single byte (0-255 range)
- 1800 to 9000 range is trickier because 9000-1800 = 7200 steps in between. For this precision you would need at least 13 bits (2 ^ 13 = 8192 so can fit 7200 values). You might need to split that into two bytes (2 ^ 16) using something equivalent to [`highByte()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/highbyte/) and [`lowByte()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/lowbyte/) in Processing before sending and [`word()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/conversion/wordcast/) in Arduino (or equivalent STM32 Dev tools if not using Arduino).

For example:

```
void serialWriteWord(Serial port,int value){
  port.write(highByte(value));
  port.write(lowByte(value));
}

byte lowByte(int word){
  return (byte)(word & 0xff);
}

byte highByte(int word){
  return (byte)(word >> 8);
}
```

The serial communication part is a totally separate issue (for another question)

Comment: Good evening, I will try to explain the main purpose. Don't scold me too much. My task is so that I could use a comma "," in text fields 1 and 2, but the library has controlP5.Float - is this a floating point in the form of a point? Since you cannot put a comma without the KeypRessed condition. I need to transfer data of digits 55.5 and others through the com port. What solution should I use then without global? Or am I confusing the period in the library with a comma?

Comment: Hopefully I'm not scoling: that is not my intention :) I'm trying to help beyond the question by providing suggestions for improvement wherever possible. If I understand correctly your goal is to send floating point numbers (e.g. 55.5) to a `Serial` port and you intent to use controlP5 to allow users to input values to send, correct ? As far as I know period(`.`) is used to separate the integer from the fractional part of a floating point number: at least in English :) In other languages this may be different, however both your software (Processing sketch) and firmware need to handle this...

Comment: ...I'm not a native English speaker, however I tend to write code in (US)English (not even UK English, except maybe comments). I do that because I'm lazy and I'd rather not mess with Locale support across different platforms. Personally I'd stick to using `.` instead of `,` for floating point numbers, but the choice is yours of course. Be aware of the extra work you may need to kick serial communication consistent. What is the smallest and largest value you intent to send over serial ? (You may need to take floating point precision into account). Off-topic you need to consider how you pack...

Comment: ...the data for serial communication (e.g. a well defined serial packet of bytes (including a header, data payload and perhaps extra data for checksum/CRC validation) or raw strings (in which case serial transmission errors will need to be handled)).

Comment: Yes, right with controlP5, maybe ControP5.Float would suit me, but why there is no semicolon filter in the library is strange. Is the smallest and largest value going to send over the serial link? This is 7.4-16.8 volts, or a whole 1800-9000. I will use stm32 to receive data from the application. As I understand it, with a point, you can also do it for receiving data? There is nothing terrible in this.

Comment: Looks like I got the meaning wrong "." with "," read it again now everything is clear. So I'll do it through ControlP5.Float then void public KeyPressed is unnecessary for this.

Comment: I've added a few more notes in my answer based on your comment. Glad you've worked it out. Good luck!